# Spring security and angular js ajax login

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am try to implement ajax login procedure to angular app. But the problem is that I don't understand how to do it with ajax way. I need to authenticate user and use his username as the header of websocket connections on clientside (I use STOMP Spring websockets). I don't realize how to put it together. I will appreciate if you suggest me a right way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try overriding AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFailureHandler as mentioned in the below post

https://dzone.com/articles/secure-rest-services-using